# Move to Top on showing and hiding divs in angular2

Tags: html, css, angular, angular2-directives

I am having 2 divs inside a fixed length div- Content div.
Content div has 2 div inside it - div1 and div2.
Both div are very large as compared to Content div.
User can scroll the content which is inside Content div.
User will read div1 and will then click on a button in div1 after that i am unhiding div2 and hiding div1.
But every time div2 bottom is shown, not the top data.
How can i make sure that when div1 is hided and div2 is shown, div2 top show come inside content div.

Any help will be much appreciated.

HTML CODE-

```
<div class = "completeBody">
  <div class = "header">
  </div>
  <div class = "content">
    <div class = "content1" *ngIf="showContent1">
        <div>
            top
        </div>
        <div class="bottomPoint">
            bottom
            <button (click)="showContent2()">SHOW Content2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "content2" *ngIf="!showContent1">
        <div>
            top
        </div>
        <div class="bottomPoint">
            SEE NOW YOU ARE IN BOTTOM,I WANT THAT WHEN CONTENT2 SHOULD BECOME VISIBLE,ITS TOP SHOULD COME FIRST
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "footer">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE-

```
   /* Styles go here */

.completeBody
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
.header
{
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}
.content
{
  height: 80%;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: #efefef;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}
.footer
{
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
.content1
{
  height:1000px;
  background-color: blue ;
}
.content2
{
  height:1000px;
  background-color: #909090 ;
}
.bottomPoint
{
    padding-top:950px;
}
```

TYPESCRIPT CODE-

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    templateUrl: 'app/apphtml.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/appcss.css'],
})
export class App {
  showContent1:boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.showContent1 = true;
  }
  showContent2()
  {
    this.showContent1 = false;
  }

}
```

HERE IS THE LINK FOR PLUNKER - https://plnkr.co/edit/abjZKMt0CkvJaTgaBDRm?p=preview

Comment: Please show some code. Ideally with a Plunker in this case.

Comment: share your code what you have tried

Comment: please share some code. and check. For show and hide div what are you using `hidden` or `*ngIf` ?

Comment: added the code.

Comment: It seems you need just to need scroll back to the top of the div. In angular I can give you a solution but not in typescript.

Comment: I need the solution in angular2, typescript is just a superscript of javascript

Comment: If you have a solution,please give it.I will be thankful to you

Comment: Perhaps adding `document.body.scrollTop = 0;` to the showContent2 function works.

Comment: Paul - its not working.

Comment: added the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do it is to bind our scroll container with a viewchild and then get the native properties of that element and update it.

For any reference, see the same plunker link, it is updated.